# XLoadQueryFont fails on font found with XListFonts

Tags: c, fonts, x11

I'm trying to load an OTF font into [`sflock`](https://github.com/benruijl/sflock). `sflock` uses `XLoadQueryFont()` to load the font, but for some reason the font I'm trying to load doesn't work.

I wrote a small test program which just tries to load a font and then exits. Program is shown below. It loads the font successfully for any TTF font (I tried so far) on my machine, but the OTFs I've tried don't work at all. The OTF fonts are shown by `XListFonts()`, so X does find them, but can't load them. Is there a way to load OTF fonts into X11, or do I have to use pango or similar?

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Missing argument.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Display *dsp = XOpenDisplay(0);

    XFontStruct *font = XLoadQueryFont(dsp, argv[1]);
    if (font == NULL) {
        printf("font not found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("font found.\n");
        XFreeFont(dsp, font);
    }

    XCloseDisplay(dsp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact argument you are passing to this program? Is this font listed when you type `xlsfonts`? I would say yes, use client-side fonts (almost everyone is using them these days).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks for your interest, but I have to admit that I don't remember the exact call. Just now I used `XListFonts(dsp,"*",5000,&font_count)` to list the fonts found on my system, and then tried `./foo "-misc-aurebeshinv-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso10646-1"` (with and without the quotes, `foo` being the compiled program shown above).

Comment: I found that on my system if I specify `iso10646` or any other registry for OTF fonts, `XLoadQueryFont` fails; if I specify `*`, it succeeds.

Comment: Sorry it also works with adobe registry, even though other registries like iso10646, iso8859 etc are listed as available.

Comment: You may also want to try Xft fonts.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks for the hints. Unfortunately, on my system it makes no difference whether I use `*`, `adobe` or the `iso10646` version, as long as I use an OTF font. I'll have a look at Xft fonts.

Comment: You may also want to try just `*-aurebeshinv-*` font spec.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. doesn't work. It doesn't matter how I input it, as long as it should load an OTF it will fail for me.

Comment: `*` selects the first element in the set of  registries (or whatever xlfd elements), alphabetically. In my case `adobe` is the correct one, and also the first one alphabetically. If your correct registry (or another element) is not the first one, it will not load. Maybe you need to try all of them explicitly.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I tried all possible variants for most of the OTF fonts installed on my system, none of which worked.

Comment: last suggestion, install xfontsel and try to select your font such that the example text is not grayed out

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. there is no combination in `xfontsel` for the OTF fonts which works, unfortunately. Have you tried for an OTF font, or for TTF on your machine?

Comment: No it actually doesn't work for me. Apparently the font I have tested exists as both OTF and TTF on my system. Sorry about misleading you.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks for investing time, there is nothing to feel sorry about! I guess I should try to reach out to the maintainers of X11 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into similar issues trying to use the new CommitMono OpenType font.  I run my X11 server via XQuartz on my macos desktop and I run X11 clients from various other servers, etc., including Emacs.  With the OTF files installed on macos, but not on the client machines, I see the same effect, e.g. in Emacs where the font can be "listed", but not "opened" or loaded.  When Emacs is run on the X11 server system, i.e. directly on my macos desktop within XQuartz, then it can properly display text in CommitMono.

I was able to use the converted TTF files from CommitMono, installed on my desktop to get Emacs running from another system and to display text in CommitMono, but it was ugly with excessive line spacing (as the CommitMono TTF files are currently auto-converted without fine tuning).

I think the bug here is that Xft (the X FreeType library) does not fully/properly support remote server-only OpenType fonts.  Only TrueType (TTF) fonts (and maybe "Type 1" scalable fonts) can be installed only on the X11 server as "core X11 fonts".  FontConfig code, which is used under the hood, also ends up running in the X11 client application, and so in the case of OpenType fonts it seems to require OTF files to be installed on the client systems!  Even the latest X11 ["Fonts in X11"](https://x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/fonts/fonts.html#Configuring_the_core_X11_fonts_system) documentation (see the "Troubleshooting" section) doesn't document this *bug* but instead actually claims OpenType font support should already be built into all X11 servers via the standard `freetype` module just as TureType support is.

The work-around solution is to also install the OTF files on the X11 client systems, e.g. in `$HOME/.fonts/` (and to then run `fc-cache`).  Now an Emacs running on a remote client system with the OTF files installed on it is able to display text in CommitMono using the OTF variant on the X11 server system.